# DIV Positioning different in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a pretty simple question, clearly it's an issue either with my CSS or JS, my brain is just too fried from staring at this all day to see it.

If you take a look [HERE](http://www.aifittingsproto.com/samples), what I am trying to accomplish is when someone click on either "Products, Spec Sheets, Banners, etc." it switches to the correct slide (UL element), and the arrow pointing down slides under the correct title.  Everything works dandy in Chrome; however, in Firefox - the arrow is far to the right, and in IE it's below the container.  Here's the JS:

```
var TabbedContent = {
    init: function() {  
        $(".category").click(function() {
            var background = $(this).parent().find(".selected");
            $(background).stop().animate({
                left: $(this).position()['left']
            }, {
                duration: 350
            });
            TabbedContent.slideContent($(this));
        });
    },
    slideContent: function(obj) {
        var margin = $(obj).parent().parent().find(".sliderContainer").width();
        margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
        margin = margin * -1;

        $(obj).parent().parent().find(".displayContent").stop().animate({
            marginLeft: margin + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 1
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    TabbedContent.init();
});
```

I'd paste the CSS but it's a little lengthy, it can be viewed [HERE](http://www.aifittingsproto.com/samples/css/uncompressed/cart.css) (It's under the comment "Here's the CSS for the tabbed content").  So as you can see from the JS, the arrow is supposed to slide under the correct heading in 350ms, and the associated UL slides into position.  Now the movement seems to be fine in IE and Firefox, it's just that the positioning of the pointing arrow is way off.  Hopefully someone in the community can spot my flaw.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: First thing you should try is a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Download the css file and load it before any other stylesheets and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Ran it independently on a separate page with only the css pertaining to this, js, and HTML. Still no dice, so it must be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change the `display` to `inline-block` on

```
.tabbedContent .tabs {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(tested in FF and IE - works fine)

Comment: I checked this as well, and the problem is that the block is set to display:inline. More on how browsers handle this (absolute positioning inside relative inline tags) here: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-cb.html

Comment: Beautiful, works perfectly, and @Ben D, thanks for the link, it looks like I need to refresh myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `float`s are not being set/cleared properly. Adding `float: left;` to `.selected` and to `.tabs` fixes it in Firefox (Not able to test IE at the moment)